# Area issue geometry

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I could not solve it, is it because it is missing information?  I used law of basic trigonometry

Comment: I found 8. [2-sqrt (2)]?

Comment: Nope, the area is $18-6\sqrt{5}$, Let $ABCD$ be the vertices of the square (lower-left, lower-right, upper-right, upper-left) and $F$ be the vertex of triangle with angle $45^\circ$. The key is $\angle BFD = 45^\circ$ implies $F$ is lying on a circle centered at $C$ with radius $CD = BC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @achilleHui, since $\angle ADC = 90^0 = 2 \times \angle APC$ and both angles are on the same side of AC, therefore D is the center of the circle APC. If DE is the perpendicular bisector of AP, then AE = 2.

[image]

Let the sides of the square be 2x.

In $\triangle AED, ED = … = 2 \sqrt {x^2 - 1}$ and $\tan \theta = … = \sqrt {x^2 - 1}$.

In $\triangle OBA, BA = 2x$ and $\tan \theta = \dfrac {2x}{\sqrt {6^2 – (2x)^2}}$.

Equating the two and simplifying, we get $x^4 – 9x^2 + 9 = 0$

Rejecting the other value of $x^2$, we get $x^2 = \dfrac {9 – 3\sqrt 5}{2}$.

Required result $= 4x^2$